# NetBeans will not clean and build my projects

Tags: java

I am very new to Java.  Whenever I try to perform a clean and build for my projects in NetBeans I keep getting the same errors over and over again with every project.  unbalanced quotes in -Xbootclasspath/p:'C:\Users\Sharon's Computer\Desktop\ReaderIP2\${endorsed.classpath}' No matter what the project is I still get the same message; I have never been successful in performing a clean in build in the last two weeks that I have been using NetBeans; can you help me with this problem?

Comment: Are you using ant or maven? Can you post the full text of the error?

Comment: The quote in `Sharon's Computer` is causing the problem. Unfortunately, I don't know an other solution beside saving your projects in a directory without a quote in it's path.

Comment: @jlordo I was wondering if the OP could change the `build.xml` or `pom.xml` to correct this.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: I think he's using neither ant nor maven, just the regular netbeans project builder. I'm not familiar with it, because I use eclipse.

Comment: I completely agree with others that mentioned  Sharon's Computer  as being the trouble maker.  Try saving in C:\ and see if it works.

Comment: @jlordo Netbeans doesn't have its own builder - it natively uses ant or maven.

Comment: @jlordo: Thanks for the info, didn't know that. What does it use by default? I'm pretty sure that's what OP is using...

Comment: Looks like it's ant by default. I've had a poke around and the endorsed classpath is defined in the `build-impl.xml` which has `DO NOT EDIT` in big letters at the top. You could edit this file to change the quotes about but it would be regenerated randomly.

Answer (score 1):

The quote in `Sharon's Computer` is causing the problem.

The only solution I can think of is saving your projects in a directory without a quote in the path.

Comment: I wonder if using escape character would work on this? Sharon\'s Computer?  Or would it think that \Sharon\ is a directory and \'s Computer\ is another directory.

Comment: @Noobacode hence my question about about the full error, then we would know _where_ to stick the escape...